# MySQL 8 Recursive CTE generate number of rows

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I would like to generate `n` count of random rows by using MySQL CTE. So far I have:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) AS `three`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) AS `three`
    WHERE `rn` < 10
)
SELECT * FROM cte
;
```

How to make the condition

```
WHERE `rn` < 10
```

working, assuming `rn` is a rows number returned by the recursive query?

I know that you may use:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS `rn`
```

to get the row number but how to use it? Is there any alternative solution?

I'm using MySQL 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "control" column in the CTE, that counts from one up. Then you can limit the recursive step to end when the value in that column exceeds ten (or what ever *n* is). In the outer `SELECT` then just select the column with the random values, but not the "control" column.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte
AS
(
SELECT left(md5(rand()), 8) three,
       1 i
UNION ALL
SELECT left(md5(rand()), 8) three,
       i + 1 i
       FROM cte
       WHERE i + 1 <= 10
)
SELECT three
       FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51a05866728c815e37f7bf30e41993b1)

Comment: i returns the depth and not the columns.  Columns could be 1 million but if they are in depth 5, the above query won't work .

Comment: @Thanasis: There are only exactly two columns in the CTE and exactly one in the result as a whole, there cannot be 1 million of them.

Comment: sorry brother my mistake. I meant rows. Not columns. Ur actual example measures level depth and not row count. You use Recursive for one reason. To measure sub entries of entries. Your code will probably work if there is only 1 level depth in the calculations. I will attempt to write a query with multiple WITHs which measures max columns beneath each Column. I gave you a like because you really monitor your posts even a year after the initial post !. Also I would like to mention that from MySQL 8.0.18 you may use LIMIT X at the second RECURSIVE cte argument! Just to share my 2cents

Comment: @Thanasis: The recursion stops when the `UNION`ed query results in the empty set. In this case this happens when `i + 1` exceeds `10`. The first operand (`SELECT`) to the `UNION` is `FROM` and `WHERE` less and therefore produces exactly one row.

Comment: @Thanasis:  The second one produces also only ever one row. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) states that "Each iteration of the recursive part operates only on the rows produced by the previous iteration." In the first recursive step the previous set has one row (from the `FROM` and `WHERE` less `SELECT`). So this step produces one row and so on. So the number of rows produced is ten as `i` starts with the value of `1`.

Comment: @Thanasis: Of course you can write `1000000` instead of `10` in the `WHERE` clause to get a million rows. But the query as it stands in my post won't produce a million rows but exactly ten.

Comment: @Thanasis: `LIMIT` is useless here. The second `SELECT` to the `UNION` already produces only exactly one row. There's no point to `LIMIT` to one again.